# drawing fonts above 600 dpi will not anti-alias (c#)

Tags: c#, fonts, antialiasing

(programming in C# with VS2013)

I have four images saved with different DPI (Dots Per Inch) settings: 96 dpi, 192 dpi, 384 dpi and 768 dpi. I draw on these images after loading them from file. I have set the `TextRenderingHint` to `ClearTypeGridFit`. This renders fonts very nicely using the 96, 192 or 384 dpi images. Using the image at 768 dpi, it fails to provide smooth rendering.

```
// retrieve the image from project resource
Image im = null;
im = <myproject>.Resources.image_at_96dpi;

// link a graphics instance to image instance
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(im);

// set the fonts drawing to highest quality
gr.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

// create a font and brush for drawing onto the image
var font_example = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12.0f);
var brush_example = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
var point_example = new PointF(50.0f, 50.0f);

// draw text onto the image
gr.DrawString("some text", font_example, brush_example, point_example);
```

Above code produces the wanted result (also for 192 and 384 dpi).

When changing the first three rows of above code to below code:

```
// retrieve the image from project resources
Image im = null;
im = <myproject>.Resources.image_at_768dpi;
```

The text is rendered, but is not nice / smooth / anti-aliased.

Does anybody understand why this happens?

I found out that it renders nicely when using font sizes below 9.0f on the 768 dpi image... but since the `PageUnit` is `Display` this limits me to too small fonts.

Comment: Have you tried using TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias or TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit ?

Comment: I tried TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias and this solved above limitation. Thanks for the solution L33TS!

Comment: Sure, at 600 dpi, the pixel density becomes so high that it doesn't make sense to use ClearType anti-aliasing anymore.  You then need to switch to AntiAliasGridFit.